# All app logs going into same log4j log file

Tags: maven, log4j, weblogic, weblogic-10.x

(might be co-incidence) but this problem is happening after we switched from Ant builds, to Maven.

(server is Weblogic 10.3.5)

We have several apps, each with its own log4j.properties, and each was logging into its own app.log. However, after the Maven builds, all the apps are logging into one single log file. It appears that the first app that we deployed is somehow taking precedence and log4j is writing into that file only.

In the Maven setup, `log4j.properties` is under `src/main/resources`. Here's one example of one of our `log4j.properties`:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout, logfile
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %p [%c] - <%m>%n
log4j.appender.logfile=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.logfile.File=logs/stat-calc.log
log4j.appender.logfile.MaxFileSize=4096KB
log4j.appender.logfile.MaxBackupIndex=7
log4j.appender.logfile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.logfile.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %p [%c] - %m%n
```

Has anyone come across this problem?

Comment: Where app log-files were lay early and where now?

Comment: The log files are in the weblogic domain log folder. They are still there, except that now, only one of them is being written to. All apps are writing into that one log file.

Comment: In the project pom.xml log4j had the scope attribute set to provided. That causes the log4j.jar not to be bundled in the ear. So I removed that, and now log4j is being bundled in. But the problem is still there, the one app that has log4.jar bundled in now, is still writing to the log file of another app. I restarted the server too. No effect.

Comment: Early, each application wrote logs to file stat-calc.log in the same dir? How?

Comment: No, before Maven, each app, was writing into its own log file. I have stat-calc.log, admin.log, update-ws.log, etc... After we switched to a Maven build, all of the other apps are writing into the stat-calc.log. The admin, update-ws, etc... are not being written into.

Comment: Look to each application. Does each app contain his log4j config file? Or all applications contain same log4 file?

Comment: log4j config file should be in META-INF or in root dir

Comment: Thanks. Each app has its own log4j.properties. I did move the log4j.properties for one of the apps to test it (admin) to META-INF. I can see in the ear it's under META-INF. I restarted the server. No effect. The logs are still being written to stat-calc.log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely a WebLogic classloading issue.  We have solved this in the past by adding a  `META-INF/weblogic-application.xml` file with a format something like this: :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<weblogic-application xmlns="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/100"   
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <prefer-application-packages>
        <package-name>org.apache.log4j.*</package-name>
    </prefer-application-packages>
</weblogic-application>
```

This works for ear files.  For wars, you need a `WEB-INF/weblogic.xml`:

```
<weblogic-web-app xmlns="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-web-app">
    <container-descriptor>
        <prefer-web-inf-classes>true</prefer-web-inf-classes>
    </container-descriptor>
</weblogic-web-app>
```

Comment: Thank you. That must be it. I did add the prefer-web-inf-classes to the weblogic.xml for the web app. Now I'm running into NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/cglib/proxy/Enhancer
which is in cglib-nodep-2.1_3.jar and is being bundled in the war. But for some reason it can't find the Enhancer class.

Comment: Make sure the app is not including `weblogic.jar`, `servlet.jar` etc. in the `WEB-INF/lib` directory.  If they are specified in your POM make sure they have `provided` scope. If that doesn't help, I'll refer you to the [WebLogic classloading docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs100/programming/classloading.html) or try Googling, because I've reached the limit of my knowledge in this area.

Comment: Also, if you are deploying the war inside an ear, the ear solution might be a better choice, since it allows you to configure class loading for specific packages.

Comment: That did it! Thanks! I packaged the war inside an ear, and in the META-INF for the ear I included the weblogic-application.xml with the elements you suggested. Thanks so much!